# Help needed defining closed form of recursive formula

Tags: recurrence-relations

The recursive formula is

$a_n$ = 1.28($a_{n-1}$ ) - (.28$a_{n-1}$)^2

I would like to transform this into one side of the equation being $a_n$ such that the equation requires no recursion (allowing me to solve for large values of n)

$a_0$ = 0.12

Comment: Please enclose the whole formula with two dollar signs to represent it .

Comment: There is generally no way to do the transformation you want, Spaaz. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by calculating $a_n$ for large $n$? This particular sequence monotonically converges, so $a_n$ just becomes a better and better approximation of the limit as $n$ grows larger.